# Largest and smallest roots in a cubic equation

Tags: polynomials

How could I obtain the largest and smallest roots of this equation.

$$Y^3 - (1 - C_{1}) Y^2 + (A - C_{1} + C_{2}) Y - C_{2} = 0 $$

The three roots are real, positive, between $0$ and $1$.

I need to be sure they are the smallest and the largest in order to continue with really tedious work.

Any help wll be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hand it to Maple or Mathematica --- it'll find all the roots.

Comment: @Gerry. The problem is that Mma generates one real root plus two conjugated complex. How to know that they are all real and to pick the two extremes before lauching an enormous symbolic work. Thanks

Comment: @Gerry.Is there a trig method which provides the roots in the proper order ?

Comment: The discriminant will tell you whether you are in the three-real-root or the one-real-root case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the formula of Cardano for the roots of an equation.But before using you should make a substitution $y=x+\frac{1-C_{1}}{3}$.You will get an equation
$$x^3+px+q=0,$$ which can easy be dealed with in Maple,Mathematica,Matlab(choose one). There you can get the formula for the roots and minimize (maximize) them.

Comment: thanks but what I need is to pick the largest and the smallest root before lauching a quite enormous calculation, all of that being symbolic and not numeric.

Comment: @Paul.Is there a trig method which provides the roots in the proper order ?

Comment: There is a formula, but it does not provide the proper order. I meaned that you could get those explicit formulas and deal with then in depence on the values of $C_{1},C_{2}$

Comment: Go ahead, please

Comment: $$x_{k=1,2,3}=2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\frac{3q}{2p} \sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right)-k\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$
This is formula. But is does not provide, which of roots is bigger or less. As you said that there are exactly 3 roots, $p<0$ anyway, so this formula is correct

Comment: if you make k=0, you get the largest root. If you make k=2, you get the smallest. Thanks again.